# Automatically acquire a checkout lock when checking out (tfs2012)?

Tags: tfs, vcs-checkout

When using a server workspaces is there any way to automatically acquire a checkout lock. I know you can go through Tools-->Options and under "Check-in Items-->Edit" specify "Prompt for lock on checkout" but we want it to automatically happen and not have to throw a dialog in their face and make them choose a checkout lock. We are in the process of migrating to TFS from sourcesafe and we have a few users that don't need the flexibility of local workspaces and/or multiple checkouts. They are going to freak out if they ever get a merge conflict dialog. Any way to make tfs act just like sourcesafe?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Disable multiple checkouts**

Team -> Team Project Settings-> Source Control -> Untick "Allow Multiple Checkouts"

**Set Server Workspaces to be the default**

Team -> Team Project Collection Settings-> Source Control -> WorkSpace Settings -> Server Workspaces

Comment: I want to make exclusive locks too, but even after doing these two things you said, "check out lock" option doesn't appear (not to mention no exclusive check out happens) when right clicking and chosing "check out". Only "unchanged" and "check in". What else am I could be missing?

Comment: Are you using TFS2012 with local workspaces? they work completely different. You need to use server workspaces to enable the locking features.

Comment: If using VS Online, you need to connect from Visual Studio, and in the Team Explorer window go to Settings.  There will be two "Source Control" options under settings, the one under Team Project Collection contains these settings.

Comment: I'm using TFS 2015 with VS 2012 and VS 2015 and this does not seem to be sufficient. I can still checkout files on both VS's. Before we where using TFS 2012 which was working.