# How use TFS files lock like Source safe?

Tags: tfs, visual-sourcesafe

we used Source safe in previous projects, in source safe when a developer checkout a file or project or solution another developers can not checkout it but in TFS 2013 another developer can checkout it and then TFS merge all changes

I want when a developer checkout file or ... another developers can not checkout it while the developer check in it ! we dont like merge tools :D we love preemptive :D

How config TFS for this purpose ???

Comment: You might find that you're fighting against the tide. Most modern version control systems are based around concurrent development.

Comment: we dont like concurrent development !!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically acquire a checkout lock when checking out (tfs2012)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069584/automatically-acquire-a-checkout-lock-when-checking-out-tfs2012)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In team explorer goto settings >Team Project > Source control

Under check-out settings Uncheck the Enable multiple check-out box

[image: enable multiple check-out]