# Team Foundation Server check-in check-out

Tags: sourcesafe-6.0

My team currently uses Visual SourceSafe (VSS) 6.0 as the source control for our team project. Recently we decided the switch to the latest source control technologies such as Team Foundation Server.

SourceSafe has check-in/check-out functionality which works in this way:  when I check-out a file, any other team member cannot edit the file until I check-in.  Now I am playing with team foundation server, and I am looking for the similar functionality in TFS. But it looks like even if I check-out a file, other team member can still edit and check-in the file. So when I want to check-in my own file I have to resolve all conflicts as now server has different version than I have.

Can anyone tell me if is it possible in TFS to lock a file before editing, thus preventing other users to edit that file and avoiding all merge and resolving conflict issues?

I tried ‘Get latest version of item on check out’ option. But this does not work for local workspace. So if I enable this option, and do check-in, it completely removes changes in my local file that I am intended to check-in and replaces it with latest server copy.

Can anyone give me any suggestion? 
Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically acquire a checkout lock when checking out (tfs2012)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069584/automatically-acquire-a-checkout-lock-when-checking-out-tfs2012)

Comment: I did whatever proposed there .. still no luck :( I am using TFS 2013. Is the functionality different in TFS 2013 than TFS 2012?

Comment: Never mind .. solved it ... I have to check the option 'Check In-Allow other users to check out but prevent them from checking in'

Answer (score 0):

[This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242869.aspx) might be helpful for this, I believe setting off "Multiple checkout" will do what you want.